# How to automatically answer the user prompt from calling tsm command inside a .bat file

Tags: batch-file, tableau-api

I am trying to write a set of tsm maintenance commands in `.bat` for performing some clean up on my Tableau Server.
The command `tsm maintenance reset-searchserver`, asks for a user prompt `This operation will perform a server restart. Are you sure you wish to continue? (y/n):`  which I would like to answer automatically.

**Stuff I have already tried**:

1. I have already tried putting the command `tsm maintenance reset-searchserver` in a `.bat` file, say `ABC.bat`, and then typing `echo y | ABC.bat` on the command line. However, this did not work.
2. I also tried the method in which I saved the letter "y" in a text file, say Yes.txt, and then tying `ABC.bat < Yes.txt` on the command line. This did not work either.
3. Have also tried these two commands on the command line directly, they dont seem to work either:
   `echo y | tsm maintenance reset-searchserver` and
   `tsm maintenance reset-searchserver<Yes.txt`

Comment: My first thought would have been `echo y|tsm maintenance reset-searchserver` or `tsm maintenance reset-searchserver <yes.txt`

Comment: @Squashman Already tried that too. Does not work.

Comment: @Gerhard ```--ignore-prompt``` is not a legal option for ```tsm maintenance reset-searchserver```

Comment: @Gerhard both are unrecognized options

Comment: ok, cool, I know it works for backup, but not sure about `reset-searchserver` Will delete comments to clean up

Comment: @Gerhard, yeah for backup and some other maintenance commands ```--ignore-prompt``` is a recognized option. Wonder why it does not exist for ```reset-searchserver```.Annoying!

Answer (score 0):

you should use macro:

1. Edit macro file, put all your scripts and save as File.mac
2. Open administrative client and run:

   C:\Program Files\Tivoli\TSM\baclient>dsmadmc -id=admin -pass=password macro c:\tmp\macro-file.mac